# Update JS Variable in HTML Whenever It Changes

Tags: javascript, html

There is minus, plus buttons next to a number input. Below these, a buy now button with getting values from HTML and passing to href URL. **How can i update quantity in the href URL when i click minus/plus buttons everytime (quantity value changes)?**
I wrote the code below and it shows only the button in new tab when click minus/plus i need to update the button URL in the same page.

URL: `product.php?id=1&addtocart=1&qty=1`

```
<td id="pid">1</td>
                    <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();ifquantitychanges();"</button>
                    <input id="quantity" min="0" value="1" type="number" max="5">
                    <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp();ifquantitychanges();"></button>

        <script>
        
        function ifquantitychanges() {
        var qty= document.getElementById('quantity').value;
                    var pid= document.getElementById('pid').innerHTML;
        var loc = "product.php?id="+ pid + "&addtocart="+ pid + "&qty="+ qty;
        
        document.write('<a href="' + loc + '"><button>Add to cart</button></a>');
}
ifquantitychanges();
            </script>
```

Screenshot: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRuSE.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFeEq.png)

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't do so. Your button onclick-submit action should by default obtain the quantity in the `<input>` and *submit* the form. Don't dynamically change the URL of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can change browser URL by accessing the `window.location.href` variable :)

```
var loc = "product.php?id="+ pid + "&addtocart="+ pid + "&qty="+ qty;
window.location.href = loc;
```

Comment: I need to change button's href in the same page, not the page URL.

Comment: Well, that was not clear when we read : "How can i update quantity in the URL when i click minus/plus buttons everytime (quantity value changes)?" 

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method where you change the url using [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) in the input where your value changes

Comment: Still same, it shows the button in new tab instead of updating in the same page. This should be solved by maybe event listener.